# linking to an svg through comments_popup_link

Tags: themes, comments

I want to remove the text in the comment section and replace it with svg which falls back to png. This is my code so far

```
     <?php comments_popup_link('<object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/comment.svg"><img src="./images/comment.png"/></object>', '1 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/comment.svg"><img src="images/comment.png"/></object>',
             '%<object type="image/svg+xml" data="./images/comment.svg"><img src="images/comment.png"/></object>'); ?>
```

I don't see anything wrong with my code plus my i have chmoded the images folder and its contents to 777, any pointers would be great. I am very new to Wordpress theme development so please excuse me if this is trivial. thanks

Comment: What does the generated markup look like?

Comment: <a href="http://localhost:234/wordpress/?p=22#respond" title="Comment on dummy 10"><object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/comment.svg"><img src="images/comment.png"></object></a>

Comment: I think the problem is with the address of the image as it gives out a 404 not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the relative URL. You have to be careful with relative URLs in WordPress. Relative URLs are interpretted by the *browser* but the browser doesn't know about the URL rewriting that happens behind the scenes.

Think about where your index file appears to be-- `http://example.com/`-- vs. where it actually is-- `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/index.php`.  Similar problems occur with image locations. The apparent location-- the path relative to the displayed URL-- tends to be wrong.

You need to provide an absolute URL for your image `src` using, probably, [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) or [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) as appropriate.